# How do you rename existing entities with a custom name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm in the process of renaming all existing villagers to "Villager" in a server I manage (fairly new to admin stuff) but I do not know what code to use. I did find one before but it was kind of a stupid move for me to not bookmark it so now I can't find it. All I know is that I need to use the `/execute` command.

Comment: First, what version of Minecraft are you on? The execute command changes drastically after 1.13.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, because I haven't been on stack exchange lately. I'm on the latest version (1.16.4)

Answer (score 1):

On 1.13+, it is:

```
/execute as @e[type=villager] run data merge entity @s {CustomName:"\"Bob\""}
```

on 1.12− it is:

```
/entitydata @e[type=villager] {CustomName:Bob}
```

Comment: That is very much correct, but I'd like to encourage you to write a small explanation on how the command works. For example, why did you choose to use `/execute` for the `/data merge` command, and not type the selector in directly?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Because `/data merge` in 1.13+ only works with one entity at a time, unlike `/entitydata` in 1.12-

Comment: I'll go try this out when I open the server later, thanks for the answer!