# How can I change the name of an entity with commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there a way to change the name of an entity with commands in Minecraft Bedrock?
I don't have access to NBT tags, so I'm not sure if this is even possible.

I found [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/379780/how-do-you-rename-existing-entities-with-a-custom-name) but the solution only works on Java edition.

Do I have to use tags for everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374587/how-do-i-summon-a-named-mob) question (with an accepted answer), it should solve your problem. Basically you can use the `/summon` command and use this format:

```
summon <entityType: EntityType> [spawnPos: x y z] [spawnEvent: string] [nameTag: string]
summon <entityType: EntityType> <nameTag: string> [spawnPos: x y z]
```

Comment: Ok so the only way is to set its name when summoned. No way to set it for an entity already created?

Comment: Pretty much, at least afaik. Minecraft commands on Bedrock edition are very abstract in my opinion...

Comment: A nice way to say "disappointing and incomplete"

Comment: Yup, I totally agree xD